# How can I access other Docker-Containers with a HTTP Request while using different nginx services?

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have two different Docker container (lets call them A and B) which are in the same network (lets call it AB_NET). The containers are specified in different `docker-compose.yml` files. Both are running their own nginx (let call it NA and NB) which are also in the same network AB_NET. If I log into A I can access B by doing curl http://A:8081 and if I log into B I can access A by doing curl http://B:8082. But I cannot reach B from A if I use a regular HTTP Request. My guess is, that the nginx of A cannot redirect the call to B (or it is not allowed). What I want to do is to read some data from B and display it in A after doing said HTTP Request. I'm running a PHP application in A and the nginx .conf file looks like this:

```
server {
    index index.html index.php;
    root /var/www/html/public/;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass A:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

I've tried to extend `try_files` with another location with a proxy_pass to B:

```
server {
    index index.html index.php;
    root /var/www/html/public/;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string @B;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass A:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location @B{
        rewrite ^ / break;
        proxy_pass http://B:8082;
    }
}
```

That "works" in a sense that I can reach B but the request is never send back to A. I just see the output of B. But I want it to send back to A where I can process it. I cannot even interrupt the request anymore so that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Can you clarify the setup a little bit?  It sounds like the Docker networking works – `docker exec A curl http://B:8082` successfully makes a regular HTTP request – so can you show the call that fails and the error you get?  Is the Nginx setup core to the problem or an attempt to address it?

Comment: Lumen (the php framework I used) couldn't handle the response for whatever reason. If I just return it directly it works. Sorry, I've searched in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, that was my mistake, it was probably a problem with Lumen (the php framework I used). It works, I was just searching in the wrong place.